# Printing nested boxes with Format

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to achieve this with Format and boxes (mainly to get rid of the depth parameter):

```ml
let rec spaces n =
  match n with
  | 0 -> ""
  | n -> "  " ^ spaces (n - 1)

let rec fact n d =
  Format.printf "%sinput: %d\n" (spaces d) n;
  let r = match n with 0 -> 1 | n -> n * fact (n - 1) (d + 1) in
  Format.printf "%soutput: %d\n" (spaces d) r;
  r

let () = Format.printf "%d@." (fact 5 0)
```

```
input: 5
  input: 4
    input: 3
      input: 2
        input: 1
          input: 0
          output: 1
        output: 1
      output: 2
    output: 6
  output: 24
output: 120
```

This is as far as I've gotten:

```ml
let rec fact n =
  (* alternative, seems equivalent *)
  (* Format.printf "input: %d@;<0 2>@[<v>" n; *)
  Format.printf "@[<v 2>input: %d@," n;
  let r = match n with 0 -> 1 | n -> n * fact (n - 1) in
  Format.printf "@]@,output: %d@," r;
  r

let fact n =
  Format.printf "@[<v>";
  let r = fact n in
  Format.printf "@]";
  r

let () = Format.printf "%d@." (fact 5)
```

```
input: 5
  input: 4
    input: 3
      input: 2
        input: 1
          input: 0

          output: 1

        output: 1

      output: 2

    output: 6

  output: 24

output: 120
```

I can't get rid of the additional newlines. The `@,` break hint after `input` is needed, or inputs are all on one line. If I remove the break hint before `output`, I get this:

```
input: 5
  input: 4
    input: 3
      input: 2
        input: 1
          input: 0
            output: 1 <-- misaligned
          output: 1
        output: 2
      output: 6
    output: 24
  output: 120
```

which is close, but now the indentation of `output`s no longer line up with their `input`s (similar problem/solution described here: https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/format-module-from-the-standard-library/2254/9). What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICS, The best solution goes like this:

```ml
let rec fact n =
  Format.printf "@[<v>@[<v 2>input: %d" n;
  let r = match n with
    | 0 -> 1
    | n -> Format.printf "@,"; n * fact (n - 1)
  in
  Format.printf "@]@,output: %d@]" r;
  r
```

If you don't want to touch the computing part (to make it parameterized, for instance), and you can accomodate for a leading new line:

```ml
let rec fact n =
  Format.printf "@,@[<v>@[<v 2>input: %d" n;
  let r = match n with 0 -> 1 | n -> n * fact (n - 1) in
  Format.printf "@]@,output: %d@]" r;
  r
```

Comment: Thanks! I got tripped up by the fact that boxes set the indentation of the _next_ line, so having the leading newline to turn the next line into the current line makes sense. Follow-up question, why use two boxes (`@[<v>`)? I tried removing this one and it still worked. Is it just a best practice to make sure we don't output something outside a box?

Comment: If you wrap the whole thing in something, you are going to need it and it help if you start adding more non-indented output. It's also "logical": you want stuff aligned vertically but non-indented, so that's a v box.